# Disabling the mute button on internal laptop keyboard

Tags: audio, keyboard, mute

On my laptop, the mute button is jammed in a really weird position. The volume control is flickering on and off rapidly. It's really tiny and I won't be able to physically fix it unless I take apart the laptop which is glued together so that isn't an option.

Is there a way I can disable this button in windows somewhere?

Comment: Could you please post some information about your laptop? The specific make/model? Usually removing keyboards from laptops is very simple. In some HP models, keyboard controls for Audio is done via software/drivers so it can also be a case of simply uninstalling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a software solution, you might be able to use [Sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to disable the key. I use it to remap keys that I don't use but you can also use it to disable keys entirely.

Download it using the link above,Install and run it. Then click `Add`. Find the mute key in the `From Key` list, and select `Turn Key off` in the `To Key` list. Click `OK` then `Write to Registry`. There is also a feature to detect the key code by pressing the key, but you might have trouble getting the key to register if it is 'flickering'.

Comment: I wanted this to work so bad, but yeah it isn't recognizing the key.
"You pressed EO_4020" Which then says "You've entered a key SharpKeys doesn't know about"

Comment: @Phaes: So did SharpKeys work or not? Your comment suggests it didn't, but your acceptance of the answer suggests otherwise.